# Change number to string react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*** COMPLETE REACT/JS NOOB ***

My goal is to make a parameter to a react component, to a string from a number.

I want to be able to take for example 10 and turn it into 10px

Example:

```
const ProgressCircle = ({ progress, color }) => { // progress is a number

//const progressStr = progress.toString()
//const str = progress.toString();

console.log(progress);
```

progress.toString() does not work?

console.log(progress) prints 'Undefined'

How hard can it be to cast a number to a string? What am I doing wrong? Or is casting not something you can do in JS?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of code. You probably are not proving the right props to `ProgressCircle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function ProgressCircle is expecting an object as the argument, so you should pass in an object, and you should name the properties of the object you are passing in with the same names as the properties of the object in the argument.

There is no need to use `toString()` as you can just use the `+` operator to add `px` to a number, but you can use `toString()` if you want to.

```js
const ProgressCircle = ( { progress, color } ) => { 

    console.log(progress, color);
    console.log(progress+"px");
    console.log(progress.toString()+"px");
}

ProgressCircle( { "progress" : 25, "color": "red" } );
ProgressCircle( { "color": "green", "progress" : 46 } );
//  ProgressCircle( { 25, "red" } );  // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
//  ProgressCircle( { "number" : 25, "string": "red" } ); // undefined undefined undefinedpx
```